# JavaScript Basic Maths Calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question might sounds stupid but I'm a newbie. My goal is to create a calculator based on JavaScript on my website. First multiplication works, however the other ones, I tried many things and nothing seems to work.

Here's the code below, that works at the beginning.

Feel free to ask any question if necessary, thanks for your time!

```
<script data-info='hacks-body'>
// on lost hours input
$('#input-lost-hours').on('input', function(){
  // update fee per hour text
  $('#text-lost-hours').text(formatNumber($(this).val()));  
  // update total fee text
  $('#text-monthly-fee').text(formatNumber(calculateTotalFee()));
});

// on cost hour inout
$('#input-hour-cost').on('input', function(){
  // update total hours text
  $('#text-cost-hour').text(formatNumber($(this).val()));  
  // update total fee text
  $('#text-monthly-fee').text(formatNumber(calculateTotalFee()));
});

// on budget
$('#input-monthly-budget').on('input', function(){
  // update total hours text
  $('#text-freelance-budget').text(formatNumber($(this).val()));  
  // update total fee text
  $('#text-total-budget').text(formatNumber(calculateTotalFee()));
});

// calculate total fee
function calculateTotalFee(){
  // get fee per hour value
  const monthCost = Number($('#input-lost-hours').val());
  // get total hours value
  const costHr = Number($('#input-hour-cost').val());
  // get monthly budget + service fee
  const monthBudget = Number($('#input-monthly-cost').val());
  // service fee
  const servFee = Number($('#text-service-fee').val());
  // multiply per hour value by total hours to get total fee
  return monthCost * costHr;
}

// format number function
// e.g. 3500 becomes 3,500
function formatNumber(num){
  return new Intl.NumberFormat().format(num);
}
</script>
```

I tried to add different functions, and separate them, but once I modify something, it goes all broken, and nothing is working.

Comment: Why have you asked this question again without adding any extra details? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74898942/javascript-calculator You didn't respond to my request to add more details there either!

Comment: My original comment: _"I tried many things and nothing seems to work."_ is hardly a detailed explanation of the debugging you have already done. You, also, haven't given us much of an explanation of how it's not working. Please be as detailed as you can about your expectations vs what actually happens. Pretend we've never seen this code before and have no idea what is supposed to happen.